# How to fill the the char or string array [6,6] that user has given me and showing it to textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, windows-forms-designer

[This is a pic of changed indexes but i have to do thus with char](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay7wH.png)I have created a Windows Form C# application the user sets the values of a 6x6 char or string array i dont know how to fill the textbox and show it properly, and i need a method to show it.
"//Dont worry about this part. Than i have to rotate the elements from rows 0,2,4 put them in colums 1,3,5 and elements from rows 1,3,5 putting them in colums 0,2,4 than tell how many "M" are in total at the two last rows".

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        char[,] matrica = new char[6,6];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void btnvazhdo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] ndaj = txtshkruaj.Text.Split(',');

            matrica = new char [ndaj.Length]; // one Error here :(

            for (int j = 0; j < matrica.GetLength(0); j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < matrica.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    matrica[i,j] = char.Parse(ndaj[i]);
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < matrica.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrica.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    matrica[i, j] = char.Parse(txtshkruaj.Text);
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < matrica.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrica.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    lblparaqit.Text += matrica[i, j] + " ";
                }
                lblparaqit.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share some input data, expected output and the actual output?

Comment: `matrica = new char [ndaj.Length]` don't you need to specify the second dimension also? You're trying to assign a `char[,]` to a `char[]`

Comment: `char.Parse(txtshkruaj.Text)` will throw an exception if the `txtshkruaj.Text` string is longer than one character. And even if it is one character, the loops containing this line of code will simply insert the same character into every index in the array

Comment: `matrica[i,j] = char.Parse(ndaj[i]);` <-- Here you're only using `i` as the index, so every row in `matrica` will have the same column values. You might consider using `ndaj[j * i]` if you want to fill all the indexes with different values (and assuming `nadaj` is at least `(matrica.GetLength(0) - 1) * (matrica.GetLength(1) - 1) ` elements in length.